# Tridion 2013 SP1: Content Delivery .NET - Unable to locate java runtime

Tags: 2013-sp1

When I start our .NET website, I see the following error in the Event Viewer:

[image]

This results in no Tridion logging and links that can't be resolved.
I already checked the JAVA_HOME environment variable, and that one is correct.
The following Java version is installed:

[image]

In the registry editor the following information is found:

[image]

I also check the license file and the references to the license file in all the config files and they are also correct.

Comment: What is the installation path of your JRE? Does it match what is shown in the Registry for the JavaHome variable?

Comment: Yes, it does match (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79)

Comment: Hmm, but in your screenshot of the registry above the path is shown as "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"

Comment: You're right. I am confused now. I changed the JavaHome in registry to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 also, but it's still not working (after restart of server). But I am confused now because the jre7 folder has only a lib and a bin folder in it. And the jdk1.7.0_79 folder has a bin, lib, but also a jre filder (which contains its own lib and bin). Should the javahome path then be C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre?

Comment: Try taking off the "\jre" at the end of the path, i.e. keep "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79". Also have this path listed under the JavaHome key for all Java 7 Registry items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

The other applications on the webserver were 64-bit applications. This application was 32-bit. So I had to install Java 32-bit.

It didn't work at first time, because the 32-bit java version has to match exactly with the installed 64-bit version. So for instance, Java 7 U79 (64-bit) will not work with Java 7 U51 (32-bit).

After installation my Registry look liked the following:

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the 32bit install? for me it's device detecting and redirects to 64b it download page

Comment: Hi @ToniMichelCaubet, you can choose the 32bit version here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html.